# rmagick on Heroku with Bundler

Tags: heroku, sinatra, bundle, rmagick

I am getting this error:

```
/app/che.rb:6:in `require': no such file to load -- rmagick (LoadError)
from /app/che.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
```

It's a sintra app: https://github.com/rtacconi/cheguevarafx/blob/master/che.rb
The Gemfile: https://github.com/rtacconi/cheguevarafx/blob/master/Gemfile
All files of the app: https://github.com/rtacconi/cheguevarafx

I tried many ways without success. It seems that during the deployment is installed, but it is not.

Please advise.

Comment: `require 'RMagick'`, not `'rmagick'`?

Answer (score 4):

use the following Gemfile

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem 'rack'
gem 'sinatra'
gem "rmagick", "2.12.2", :require => "RMagick"
```

and include rmagick with:

```
require 'RMagick'
```